# How to set Steam to always choose the same launch option for a game?

Tags: steam

Sometimes when you launch a game you have to choose between different launch options:

[image: screenshot]

Is it possible to configure Steam so the startup window is skipped and a specific options is chosen?

I my case I want Kerbal Space Program to always launch in 64-bit mode, otherwise the game crashes (because of mods).

**NOTE**: I mentioned Kerbal Space Program as an example, but the answer should be valid for any Steam game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A recent update just made it possible to do precisely this!

When you launch a game that has multiple launch options, the window now displays a checkbox always to use the selected option.

[image: The new launch options window]

The selected option can also be changed by going to the game's properties and modifying the "Launch options" dropdown field.

[image: The game properties window with the new launch options selection]

[image: The game properties window with the new launch options selection opened]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there's a way to do that in Steam directly, but you could always create a desktop shortcut to the 64 bit KSP .exe file in the local files and launch it that way. There might be a way to do it from the "Launch Options" command line in the game's Properties, but I don't know offhand.

Comment: It does work, but for other games where the options might not be linked to an executable, it would not fix anything. I also never create any shortcut on my desktop, but that's just personal preference :P

Comment: @TheBird956 I'm fairly convinced there isn't a workaround TBH.  I've seen the same discussion for other games (but with a DX9 and DX11 option instead) and there wasn't a workaround when executing from steam as far as anyone could find.  The other answer was suggested, but just like with you,  nothing actually happened

Answer (score 2):

In your steam Library, right click KSP, press *Properties*, then *Set Launch Options* at the bottom. Type the following text into the box and press OK:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Kerbal Space Program\KSP_x64.exe" %command%
```

(note: if KSP is installed in a non-default location, you will need to edit the path above to match your installation. For instance, I have the game installed on my seconday hard drive under `D:\Steam Library`)

Comment: This does not do anything. The window still shows up asking me to select an option. Also, I mentionned KSP as an example but the solution should be valid for any games.

Comment: @TheBird956 Hmm, it has worked in the past for me. Also, the exact launch option varies from game to game, so for a general answer you couldn't say much more than 'google it'

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible with Steam itself, until they make this functionality easily accessible in an update (along with so much other stuff like skipping updates that's hidden but possible), but it's already been so long it seems like they don't plan to make it publicly accessible.

If the app still works (with no updates since 2020), [SteamEdit](https://steamedit.tg-software.com/) can do this easily. It modifies a binary VDF (Valve Data Format) file to inject data, so it may trigger security software. It also requires rebuilding the file after occasional updates from Steam. The app is closed-source, but it decompiles pretty well as it's built with C#.