# How to expand (fully reveal) the Steam launch options?

Tags: steam

With Titan Quest for instance, some launch option titles cut off essentially after the game name. The modal window can't be expanded (by dragging from the edges) and there's no tooltip text. [There's no easy way to always select the preferred option](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/303159/how-to-set-steam-to-always-choose-the-same-launch-option-for-a-game).

The only way I'm aware of is to view the options  [on SteamDB](https://steamdb.info/app/475150/config/) (`steamdb.info/app/<app ID>/config/`), and perhaps by parsing local Steam configuration files.

[image: screenshot]

---

Steam build Jan 16 2022, Linux (settings → interface → 'enlarge text and icons based on monitor size' is enabled, essentially mandatory on 4K displays)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid the DirectX/Vulkan/32-bit selector when starting Hades?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/383664/how-to-avoid-the-directx-vulkan-32-bit-selector-when-starting-hades)

Comment: @l3l_aze The suggested answer addresses this question https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/303159/how-to-set-steam-to-always-choose-the-same-launch-option-for-a-game, and for Hades specifically.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Sorry, lol. It may also be possible to edit the Steam skin to make this window larger, but it would still be limited so could be broken for another game whereas SteamEdit (if it works) could just edit those long strings of text. I don't remember how to do skins, but there's documentation online.

Comment: @l3l_aze Fully expand the launch option descriptions, see the SteamDB page I linked if you haven't already. I haven't used skins since they tend to not to see any further development (can be broken by the Steam client updates), but I may if there's a 4K-optimized one especially.

Comment: I meant about your first comment above, it just doesn't make sense to me. About skins, I was referring to editing the default skin yourself to make the window wider, or try to make the text wrap (if that's even possible), as that would be a pretty simple fix.